# UItextView detection turnoff highlight for links, phone numbers etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview, detection

I have a UITextView which contains a phone number, email address and web url. I can get the detection to work which is fine however I dont want it to change the colour of the text items to blue with underline I just want it to look normal but when you click it it does what its supposed to do. So basically white text with detection but without changing the appearance of the detected item.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;`?

For more data detector types see this [UIKit Data Types Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: The question states "... white text with detection". Wouldn't your suggestion *disable* data detection?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way of achieving that using a regular UITextView.

However, you could use a `UIWebView` with `dataDetectors = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;` (or whichever configuration you need). You would also need to generate the HTML (preferably in your app) and use CSS styles to render links however you want. For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
  a:link {
    text-decoration: none; color:white;
  }
</style>
```

Might seem a little quirky... but it's worth a shot! (I haven't tested this in practice, please let me know if it works.. Thanks).